# How to cite a chapter by X in a book by Y edited by Z

Tags: biblatex, citing

I need to cite the introduction to a collection of short stories. The author of the book itself is the short story writer (Y), but it is an edited collection, so it has an editor (Z). The introduction is written by scholar X. So I want my output to look something like this:

X (2015). "Introduction". In: Y: *Short Stories*. Ed. by Z. London: London Press, p. 1-5.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use `author` to denote the author of the specific chapter you are referring and `bookauthor` to the author of the book.
On the other hand, `biblatex` also provides an `introduction` field that you can set. But i  guess you will prefer the first method.

[image: newtolatexBiblatexCiteChapExt]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @inbook{intro,
        editor={Mickey Mouse},
        author={Donald Duck},
        bookauthor={Don Rosa},
        title={introduction to the book},
        booktitle={Comics of Don Rosa},
        date=1999,
        publisher={London Press},
        pages={1-5},
        introduction={Carl Barks},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{intro}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! I knew there'd be a simple solution.